# Can't get regex to work

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am trying to figure out how to write an `regex` that will match a time. The time can look like this: `11:15-12:15` or `11-12:15` or `11-12` and so on. What i currently have is this:

```
\\d{2}:?\\d{0,2}-{1}\\d{2}:?\\d{0,2}
```

which does work until a date comes along. This `regex` will capture if a string like this comes `2013-11-05`. I don't want it to find dates. I know i should use `Lookbehind` but i can't get it to work.

And i am using `Jsoup` `Element` `getElementsMatchingOwnText` method if that information is of any interest.

The time string is included in a html source. like this: (but with more text above and below)

```
<td class="text">2013-11-04</td>
```

Comment: Do the times always appear as separate "words" bounded by whitespace?  If so, you could use `(\s|^)...(\s|$)` to force the character before and after the expression to be whitespace or beginning/end of a line. (Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/gujTvWYdRb)

Comment: Simple method: [`((\d{2}(:\d{2})?)-?){2}`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%28\d{2}%28%3A\d{2}%29%3F%29-%3F%29{2}&input=11%3A15-12%3A15%20or%2011-12%3A15%20or%2011-12%0A%0AMatch)

Comment: @mellanmokb that would work if it would be seperated "words" but they are not, the time is included in a html source. like this: 
<td class="text">2013-11-04</td>

Comment: @JohanLindkvist I believe that I've come up with a good way to do it.  It's verbose, but definitely accounts for everything and comes with a good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  Start with the base regex:

```
\d{1,2}(:\d\d)?-\d{1,2}(:\d\d)?
```

That is:

- one-to-two digits, optionally followed by : and two more digits
- followed by a hyphen
- followed by one-to-two digits, optionally followed by : and two more digits

This matches all your core cases:

```
11-12
1-2
1:15-2
10-3:45
2:15-11:30
```

etc.  Now mix in negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to invalidate matches that appear within undesired contexts.  Let's invalidate the match when a digit or dash or colon appears directly to the left or right of the match:

The negative lookbehind:  `(?<!\d|-|:)`
The negative lookahead:   `(?!\d|-|:)`

Slap the neg-lookbehind at the beginning, and the neg-lookahead at the end, you get:

```
(?<!\d|-|:)(\d{1,2}(:\d\d)?-\d{1,2}(:\d\d)?)(?!\d|-|:)
```

or as a Java String (by request)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d|-|:)(\\d{1,2}(:\\d\\d)?-\\d{1,2}(:\\d\\d)?)(?!\\d|-|:)");
```

Now while the lookaround has eliminated matches within dates, you're still matching some silly things like 99:99-88:88 because \d matches any digit 0-9.  You can mix more restrictive character classes into this regex to address that issue.  For example, with a 12-hour clock:

For the hour part, use

```
(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])
```

instead of

```
\d{1,2}
```

For the minute part use

```
(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])
```

instead of

```
\d\d
```

Mixing the more restrictive character classes into the regex yields this nearly impossible to grok and maintain beast:

```
(?<!\d|-|:)(((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]))(:((0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])))?-(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(:((0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])))?)(?!\d|-|:)
```

As Java code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d|-|:)(((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]))(:((0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])))?-(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(:((0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])))?)(?!\\d|-|:)");
```

Comment: For "01-12:15-" you match "01-12".

Comment: I posted one that I believe works in every case, but it is quite verbose.

Comment: @Steve Yes, but this is not a valid time range.  Look at his example time ranges.  None of them have a trailing dash.  Ranges do not end with a `-`.  :)

Comment: @SteveP. Oh, you're absolutely right!  What if I add : to the negative lookaround?  Edited.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I think that looks correct, but you just need to "javify" it and replace the non-trailing `\d` with legit possibilities.  For non-military time here it is: `"(?<!\\d|-|:)((?:0?[1-9]|1[1-2])(:[0-5][0-9])?-(?:0?[1-9]|1[1-2])(:[0-5][0-9])?)(?!\\d|-|:)"`

Comment: You can recall you lookbehind in your lookahead: `"(?<!(\\d|-|:))(\\d{1,2}(:\\d{2})?-\\d{1,2}(:\\d{2})?)(?!\2)"`

Comment: @SteveP. Thanks for the feedback.  I added a variant that imposes the 1..12 (hour) 00..59 (minute) restrictions and pasted a Java-escaped version.  I'll leave the 24-hour version as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl \2 recalls the actual text matched by the lookaround, not the regex pattern itself.  This is not what you want.  You have to repeat the pattern in the lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much and nice explanation. That was a bit more than i initially thought.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method:

`((\d{2}(:\d{2})?)-?){2}`

A safer; more verbose regular expression:

```
([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9]))?-([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9]))?
```

Example in action:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class App {
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";
    private static final String TIME_RANGE = "([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9]))?-([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9]))?";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String passage = "The time can look like this: 11:15-12:15 or 11-12:15 or 11-12 and so on.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(TIME_RANGE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(passage);
        int count = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String time1 = formattedTime(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(3));
            String time2 = formattedTime(matcher.group(4), matcher.group(6));
            System.out.printf("Time #%d: %s - %s\n", count, time1, time2);
            count++;
        }
    }

    private static String formattedTime(String strHour, String strMinute) {
        int intHour = parseInt(strHour);
        int intMinute = parseInt(strMinute);

        return String.format(TIME_FORMAT, intHour, intMinute);
    }

    private static int parseInt(String str) {
        return str != null ? Integer.parseInt(str) : 0;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Time #0: 11:15 - 12:15
Time #1: 11:00 - 12:15
Time #2: 11:00 - 12:00
```

Comment: This also matches: "1234"

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it's slightly longer, and less intuitive than mine.

Comment: This matches 18-12:15, for example.

Comment: 24-Hour time? *wink* *wink*

Comment: Yeah, but with mixing the two doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Matches `13-11` from `2013-11-05`.  Not desirable.